# Create new database in php with SQLite3

Tags: php, database, sqlite

How to create a new database in PHP with SQLite3?

```
$db = new SQLite3($dbname);
```

just opens the db, but I want to create if not exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To create you do use the `new` statement:

```php
// create or open (if exists) the database
$database = new SQLite3('myDatabase.sqlite');
```

If you have named a database that doesn't exist it should get created.

Comment: try{
 $db = new SQLite3($dbname);
}  catch(Exception $exception){
 echo $exception->getMessage();
} give me : Unable to open database: unable to open database file

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the folder where you're trying to create the new database?

Comment: Thinked I already granted permissions, my bad :-( , thanks you for your help

Comment: And how to create table with fields in it?

Comment: @user4271704  $table_create_query = "create table books(id integer pirmary key, name text, jild int, comment text)";
         $db->exec($table_create_query);