# View database file trough php

Tags: php, sql, database, iis

I want to make a script in PHP which will be viewing database only from ".sql" file without any phpmyadmin or sql server (with data sort). Is it even possible? If yes could you give me some advices how to do that? Thanks in advice.

Comment: Are you in control of the file? For some fixed input you could probably parse it with PHP (please provide an example). For an arbitrary input (say user upload) it would probably be prohibitively complicated (you would essentially need to _implement_ SQL in your code).

Comment: Agree with @Rarst, this is a case of 'don't start from here'. Can you not install an open source database (say MySQL) and load your sql (which I assume to be some sort of export/backup) into it, then use ordinary SQL processing from PHP on the result?

Comment: @Rarst Yes I am in control but ive got prepared simple "database.sql" and I need to view it on website (I'm using IIS) but without any libraries and sql servers. Simple table with sortable data. I can view this file only like it shows in notepad.

Comment: As above - if you could provide an example of file and what are you looking to read from it then someone would probably be able to get you started on parsing it. :)

Comment: @Rarst [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/24f8caae47a0931ea6eeb016f77a8b3420190218192403/b498cb) `database_file` [link](https://pastebin.com/aH2sqi24)  `database_code`

Answer (score 1):

`phpmyadmin` is web software to manage databases, like MySql,

If you want do not use any sql server try to use SQLite, PHP include libraries for this [PHP-SQLite3 Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot but I guess it isn't possible to make script to show database with select statement and sort without any libraries?

Comment: I do not understand the library is included, just use, [query example](http://php.net/manual/es/sqlite3.query.php) or [init new sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085378/create-new-database-in-php-with-sqlite3)

Comment: Also, you can "Transform" a `.sql` to a SQLite Database, even in a online service [RebaseData](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-mysql-to-sqlite-online)

Comment: If my answer helps you, please do not forget to approve or vote, otherwise make a comment to improve the answer. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)